# Using new Constructor in hql query cannot find proper consturctor or could not extract ResultSet

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence

I have entities:

```
@Entity
public class Author{
    @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinTable(
            name = "author_book",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "author_id") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "book_id") }
    )
   public List<Book> books;
}

@Entity
public class Book{
   @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "books")
   public List<Author> authors;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "book")
   public List<Fact> facts;

   public Book(){}
   public Book(List<Author> authors, List<Fact> facts){
       this.authors = authors;
       this.facts = facts;
   }
}

@Entity class Fact{
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name="book_id")
   public Book book;
}
```

Book has more Authors and Authors can write more books. Every book has more facts about it and each act belongs only to one book.

Now what i want achieve is to recieve object of type `Book` based on author ID. The object of type `Book` should containt all authors and all facts.

I am using hibernate query for this:

```
List<Book> books = (List<Book>) session.createQuery("Select new Book (books.authors, books.facts ) FROM Author u JOIN u.books books JOIN books.facts WHERE u.id IN :ids ").setParameter("ids", authorId).list();
```

However it results in error:

> Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [Book]. Expected
>   arguments are: java.util.Collection, java.util.Collection

I have tried to adjust constructor to take Object or Collection, and cast it by myself:

```
   public Book(Object authors,Object facts){
       this.authors = (List<Author>)authors;
       this.facts = (List<Fact>)facts;
   }
```

But this complains:

> org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract
>   ResultSet

What is the right way to fetch entity with wanted data then? It Complains only about relations (e.g collections), i have not found any solution for this anywhere ( nor documentation for hql ).

Thanks for help!

Comment: When trying to figure out why an exception is thrown, it's imperative to read the complete stack trace of the exception. You chose not to post it, so we can't help. What you're doing is awful, though. Return a managed entity (i.e. select books), or return something other than an entity. But don't claim you return a Book if what you return is only two fields of a Book.

Comment: As any JPQL reference says, you cannot select multi-valued fields. You're selecting multi-valued fields. Ho hum

Comment: and if you are actually NOT using the JPA API (i.e calling some method `list` instead of `getResultList`) then kindly remove the `jpa` tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use the NEW operator with Entities!

This is for DTO (Data Transfer Object) projection.

In your case you don't even need the NEW because you can simply select the book which will be constructed by Hibernate using the default constructor and setting the fields.

```
List<Book> books = 
   (List<Book>) session.createQuery(
   "Select books FROM Author u JOIN u.books books JOIN books.facts WHERE u.id IN :ids ")
   .setParameter("ids", authorId).list();
```

and if you want to have the collections eager loaded use JOIN FETCH like:

```
List<Book> books = 
   (List<Book>) session.createQuery(
   "Select b FROM Book b JOIN FETCH b.authors a JOIN FETCH b.facts f WHERE a.id IN :ids ")
   .setParameter("ids", authorId).list();
```

Important notice:

Hibernate cannot fetch two Lists eagerly. There for I suggest to change the Lists to Sets:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "books")
public Set<Author> authors;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "book")
public Set<Fact> facts;
```

Comment: Yes however this way the collections get initialized only if they have FetchType eager, if they are lazy loaded it throws Lazyinitiallization exception, even tho i use JOIN on those tables

Comment: FETCH JOIN throws incorrect syntax: "expcted all, found join" - 
If if do JOIN FETCH or just FETCH it throws:
query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list

Comment: I was a bit fast. Sorry about that. I updated my answer. Please try this.

Comment: This complains about: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags. I have tried using     @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT) without luck

Comment: Hibernate can fetch only one List eagerly. Do you really need lists? As you don't order these you could use Set instead and everything will work.

Comment: I tried set before posting my previous comment but overlooked my mistake which resulted in error. However using Set the query return nothing. No value in set, which is incorrect

Comment: No I mean authors and facts should be Set instead of List

Comment: Yes that what i was talking about and what i did :)

Comment: Oh i see  Have you had a look at the generated SQL?